# How to add a function to an object literal in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have something like this..

```
let orders = {};
let app: {orders: object} = {orders: orders};

let getNumber = function(orders: object): number {
    //some code here
    return some value
};

app.orders[1] = 'something';
let n = getNumber(app.orders);
```

The above works. But i was trying to do this by adding the function to my 'app' object like this:

```
let getNumber = function(): number {
    return this.orders[1]; //or something

};

let app: {orders: object, getNumber: object} = {orders: orders, getNumber: getNumber};

let n = app.getNumber();
```

Which would be the JavaScript equivalent of

```
let app = {};
app.orders = {};
app.getNumber = function() {
    return this.orders[1]; //or something //anything the point is that i can act on app.orders
}


let n = app.getNumber()
```

In other words - in TypeScript can I add functions to object literals?

If the answer is no - then that's fine - I need to understand how to write it as a Class. But I am wondering if the above is possible?

Thanks

**Update:**

```
let getValue = function(): string {
    return this.orders[1]; //or something
};
let orders: {1: string} = {1: 'abc'};
let app: {orders: object } = {orders: orders};
let val = getValue.call(app);
console.log(val) ; //abc
```

Comment: The same way you add any other property.  Are you actually asking how to write a function type?

Comment: @SLaks - yes. Basically I was confused because what I was trying to do does not even work in JavaScript. I've updated my question with the TypeScript of what I was trying to do - but really the question was ill-prepared since it was based on confusion. Thanks for your intervention.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to define the type of the function:

```
type App = {
    orders: object;
    getNumber: () => number;
}

let app: App = { orders: orders, getNumber: getNumber };
```

Comment: Thanks Nitzan. That wasn't what I was looking for (since my question was a bit hazy) but is v. useful. Reminds me of Pascal Records.

Comment: It's still not clear from your question what you're asking

Comment: I'd delete it as it is not clear but since people have answered I can't / won't. Sorry.